# Create recursive tree in php failed

Tags: php, tree

now, after one day of reseachring and refactoringm, i'm going insane....

Its simple as F*, but i could not find the error.

I get a simple Id -> ParentId structur from sql sortet from low to high with recursive function. That works. Now, i want to paste it to html. The html print is ready and is working too. The one and only problem:
my "buildTree" function isnt working.. I get all of the entrys, but not as tree.... With print_r($tree) i could see, the are no more dimensions.

What i get as object from Database:

```
Id      ParentProcessId
16      NULL
17      16
18      17
19      17
20      18
21      20
```

The code:

```
    private function createTree(&$list, $parent = array()){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($list as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l->Id])){
            $l->Children = $this->createTree($list, $list[$l->Id]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: Did you try making the function public?

Comment: How does initial `$list` look like?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski Why public? It's not needed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you do get all the entries as a result in $tree, that means that `isset($list[$l->Id])` is never true for some reason. My guess is that $list is a zero based array that looks something like this:

```
$list => [
   0 => [ Id => 16, ParentProcessId => NULL],
   1 => [ Id => 17, ParentProcessId => 16],
   (...)
]
```

When processing `isset($list[$l->Id])` for the first entry this looks for the 16th entry in $list which does not exist. I don't think this check is needed. Instead we should check if the selected item is a child of the current parent (using $parent which btw was unused in your code) and only than add it to the tree.

I think this might work, there might be a more efficient way though:

```
private function createTree(&$list, $parent = array()){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($list as $k=>$l){
        if((!isset($parent->Id) && !isset($l->ParentProcessId)) 
         || $l->ParentProcessId == $parent->Id){
            $l->Children = $this->createTree($list, $list[$l->Id]);
            $tree[] = $l;
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```